Listening to another topic using KafkaReciver after initializing it
I have a java spring service that consumes messages from multiple kafka topics and produces them into a single topic after some modifications using reactor and web flux, the service gets the topics in which he need to receive from using  another rest service I have that returns brokers and topic names, so there is a bean that initializes when the service is starting up and fetches all  topics and brokers, the service has a reactor process that his function is
this.kafkaFactory.doStart() .map() … Subscribe();
doStart() function starts consuming messages from each topic in the list of topics
now I have a problem, if there is a new topic I need to restart the app in order for the bean to be initialized with the new topic and brokers, I don’t like the idea of restring as it takes time and maybe there is a simpler way that involves the KafkaReciver reviving from another topic instead of restarting the whole app

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
